# How do I purchase Litecoins?

Tags: exchanges, litecoin

How do I purchase Litecoins? I'm after some fast in Australia! Also is it possible to convert litecoin into bitcoin?

What exchanges do you recommend if any for this.

Many Thanks,

Bill

Comment: You can try my exchange www.coinspot.com.au :)  It's really easy to buy and the prices really good.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to purchase litecoins is to purchase bitcoins first. Once you have the bitcoins you can exchange bitcoin for litecoin on www.btc-e.com.

Soon mt-gox will support litecoin and bitcoin exchanges such as https://www.bitcointrader.com.au will support litecoin as well as bitcoin soon!

Comment: The 7.6% fee is pretty steep...